# kdb: can I use the set keyword to achieve @[`.;`upd;:;.some.function]?

Tags: kdb

Say there's an existing function definition `.my.func:{[tbl;data] ...}` and I want to set the `upd` function to this lambda.

#### Are the two lines below equivalent?

```
@[`.;`upd;:;.my.func]; / #1
`upd set .my.func; / #2
```

Asking because I see a lot of #1 in the codebase I work with, but #2 seems more succinct, so was wondering if they're somehow different.

---

I checked https://code.kx.com/q/ref/amend/
"Amend at" `@[d; i; v; vy]`

This seems to simply define the function `upd` in the global namespace.

- d = `` `. ``
- i = `` `upd ``
- v = `:`
- vy = `.my.func`

After running #1/#2 myself, `` get`. `` also seems to suggest #1/2 are equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines are not equivalent in the scenario where `\d` is used to change namespace. In the examples above `set` creates the variable in the current namespace and this happens to be the global namespace. `@` creates the variable in the global namespace.

Example for `set` using `.test` namespace creates `.test.upd` instead.

```
d).my.func:{x}
q)\d .test
q.test)`upd set .my.func;
q.test)upd
{x}
q.test)\d .
q)upd        / upd does not exist in global namespace
'upd
  [0]  upd
       ^
q).test.upd  / upd exists in .test namespace
{x}
```

Example for `@` using `upd2` to highlight differences to `upd` example above. `upd2` is created in the global namespace.

```
q)\d .test
q.test)@[`.;`upd2;:;.my.func];
q.test)upd2  / upd2 does not exist in .test namespace
'upd2
  [0]  upd2
       ^
q.test)\d .
q)upd2       / upd2 exists in global namespace
{x}
```

Answer (score 3):

Following on from Thomas' answer, it's also helpful to know that you can use `@` to create your function in the current namespace also. The [d](https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#d-directory) system command, without an argument, will return the current namespace, and you can use this as the first parameter to `@`.

```
q).my.func:{x}
q)\d .test
q.test)\d
`.test
q.test)system"d"
`.test
q.test)@[system"d";`upd;:;.my.func]
`.test
q.test)upd
{x}
```

Note that this method will only work once the namespace has been initialized first, i.e. something else must exist in the namespace, otherwise you'll see a `'type` error.

```
q)key`
`q`Q`h`o`test
q)\d .new
q.new)@[system"d";`upd;:;.my.func]
'type
q.new)type each(.new;.test)
0 99h
```

Answer (score 3):

> Asking because I see a lot of #1 in the codebase I work with, but #2 seems more succinct, so was wondering if they're somehow different.

You can still use `set` to assign a value to a variable in the global namespace regardless of a namespace you're currently in, you just need to be a bit more explicit:

```
q)`upd set .my.func   / sets upd in the current namespace
q)`..upd set .my.func / sets upd in the global namespace
q)\d .test
q.test)`upd set {x+1}
`upd
q.test)`..upd set {x+42}
`..upd
q.test)upd
{x+1}
q.test)\d .
q)upd
{x+42}
```